# Fancyhdr with report: Format page numbering on chapter's first page

Tags: fancyhdr

In my `.tex` document I use the following `fancyhdr` settings:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{Another Text}
\fancyhead[R]{Some Text}
\rfoot{Page \thepage \hspace{1pt} of \pageref{LastPage}}
```

Than means that over footer the page numbering will get displayed as:

[image]

But on pages such as contents page and chapter page the page numbering is displayed as:

[image]

So how I can set a uniform way to display the page numbering?

Comment: Please don't post such fragments only. We have this question basically every other day and it is not related to `xetex` at all. The chapter start page uses `plain` style internally and not `fancy`. Possible solution `\fancypagestyle{plain}{}`, will make the plain style 'empty', such that `fancy` is still active

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to solve this problem you should also put the following:

```
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \fancyhf{}
    \rfoot{Page \thepage \hspace{1pt} of \pageref{LastPage}}
}
```

Resulting the following fancy settings:

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{Univercity Of Peireus}
\fancyhead[R]{Desyllas Dimitrios - Ioannis Anagnwstou}
\rfoot{Page \thepage \hspace{1pt} of \pageref{LastPage}}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \fancyhf{}
    \rfoot{Page \thepage \hspace{1pt} of \pageref{LastPage}}
}
```